# Fabricjs: loadFromDatalessJSON: load multiple svg file as object from saved design error

Tags: fabricjs

While i am trying to load dataless json , which contain multiple svg files as object

Load svg method:

issue only comes while i am loading multipath svg

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(src, function(objects, options) {

  var img = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  img.set('sourcePath', src);
  current.options.currentCanvas.add(img).renderAll();

  img.set({
    left: fabric.util.getRandomInt(40, 80),
    top: fabric.util.getRandomInt(40, 80),
    objID: newID,
    uploadBaseType: 'svg',
    origingSVG: src,
  });
}, null, true);
```

I save using 
 `JSON.stringify(current.options.createdCanvases[0].toDatalessJSON());`

Editing :

```
canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(output, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {});
```

//getting error at editing load from dataless json
it returns error on:fabric.require.js:441:

```
objects.forEach(function(o, index) {
```

This is because while i am saved datalessjson by adding

```
obj.sourcePath = obj.origingSVG(oringinal path of svg),
```

it contain objects key in objects data so after first iteration value of objects replace by url and foreach stop.